# Late-binding static calls - C# 4.0

Tags: .net, dynamic, late-binding

My goal is to be able to use intellisense, while still instructing the compiler to generate late-binding code (i.e. CallSites and Binders).

Say I have

```
class MyDynamicDataProvider
{
   public int Data{get;set}
}
```

I want to write:

```
MyDynamicDataProvider provider = new MyDynamicDataProvider();
int x = provider.Data;
```

I want the Data property call to be late-bound. Yet currently, if I don't declare the `provider` variable as dynamic, the compiler will pre-bound the call. i.e. in runtime, the value stored in the property's backing field will be returned.

At the same time, I want the intelllisense while coding, which means that I should declare the provider using the appropriate type.

Is there any way of acheiving both ends simultanously (using static declarations for intellisense, while relying on dynamic binding during runtime)?

Edit 1:
One might wonder why not just use the getter to perform whatever logic I need. The thing is that I'm trying to develop some meta-classes, which would allow developers to just define classes and properties, use getters, setters, methods, etc., while the magic is happening by dynamic means. There would be many such types, and I'd like to avoid such redundant code in the classes themselves.

Edit 2: It would be the nice if I could declare a class with an attribute which tells the compiler to late bound all calls to members of it.

Comment: If you already know the type at compile-time, why do you want late binding?

Comment: Jon, please see my latest edit (whitin the parenthesis) which answers that.

Comment: Not really - it's still not at all clear, to be honest.

Comment: You could just use `MyDynamicDataProvider provider` during code writing (thereby benefiting from IntelliSense), and change it to `dynamic provider` when compiling.

Comment: @Yaakov: Are you trying to re-create something like the [`ExpandoObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject.aspx)?

Comment: @Yaakov: If not, you should provide us with an example that demonstrates the real use case. Your current example and explanations are not clear at all.

Comment: Daniel, no, I'm not attempting to recreate ExpandoObject; using it would still require me giving up intellisense.

Comment: About the use case, it would be too compilcated to explain here. Sorry.

Comment: @Yaakov: Funny - how do you think we should help you then?

Comment: This is a very technical question; how to make the compiler do late binding instead or early ones. The use case shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you don't actually want `dynamic`, you just want to dynamically implement the functionality for statically defined properties and methods. If that's the case, you can create the classes as abstract and then dynamically implement them.

There is several ways to do that. Either directly using Reflection.Emit, or CodeDOM to generate classes that inherit from the abstract ones. Or you could use a tool that makes this much easier (and usually somewhat slower), like [Castle DynamicProxy](http://castleproject.org/dynamicproxy/index.html).

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio can't provide intellisense on a late-bound object since it it has no idea whether or not the member actually "exists". It might be *possible* for Visual Studio to provide this out of the box - but it doesn't. The default intellisense just shuts off on a dynamic. There are two solutions:

1. If you know the member you want to call, why are you trying to use late-binding at all?
2. Some products like [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) provide pseudo intellisense by statically looking for late-bound calls that have been made else where. In the image below, it provides intellisense for `Hello` because there is code elsewhere making that call. It's clever, but it isn't foolproof either.

[image: Resharper]

Comment: This is an interesting suggestion, but I'd prefer not to rely on such tools.

Comment: If you are wanting visual studio intellisense to do this, then you are already relying on such tools- Reshaper just extends intellisense in areas that visual stuido lacks (and its pretty good, but not without its own faults).

Answer (score 1):

To do that, your best option is to *implement `Data` so it does what you want dynamically*, possibly using a facade.

If we assume you somehow have a MyDynamicDataProvider, that knows what to do when it is called as Dynamic - then you could use a statically typed facade like this:

```
 class DataProviderFacade 
 { 
     private dynamic inner;
     public DataProviderFacade(dynamic inner)
     {
         this.inner = inner;
     }

     public int Data { get { return inner.Data; } }
 }
```

That being said, I can't imagine why you would need this.

Comment: driis, please see my latest edit (whitin the parenthesis) which explains why I'm trying to avoid facades or getter code.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the open source ImpromptuInterface (via nuget) you can define static interfaces and then it will emit and cache dynamic binding code (callsites and binders) matching that interface's members. You just use a single generic extension method on object called [ActLike](http://code.google.com/p/impromptu-interface/wiki/UsageBasic) and it will statically return that interface and actually return an emitted proxy that implements that interface and is forwarding calls via c# dynamic binding (so it will work with static and dynamic objects a like).

After the one time generation of the proxy the performance cost for invoking a method is just one static invocation + one dynamic invocation.

```
public interface IMyDynamicDataProvider
{
   int Data{get;set}
}
```

...

```
IMyDynamicDataProviderprovider = new MyDynamicDataProvider().ActLike<IMyDynamicDataProvider>();
int x = provider.Data;
```